# Why do I need a PersistentVolume, if I have a PersistentVolumeClaim?

Tags: kubernetes

Every while I see these scenarios where people create a PV and a PVC to bind to it, and I wonder what's the need?

So, one can create a PVC with `volumeName: my-volume`, and have it bounded to an existing PV. Or create the PV later, in which case PVC wouldn't be bounded to any PV, and it would stay in Pending state forever, until the PV gets created with the given name.

Now, my question is why? Why do we need to create a PVC and then the PV? There are two scenarios I see it half useful:

1. When you don't want the PVC to create a PV with random name, and you
   want to control the name of the PV, but even in that scenario, just
   create the PV with the name you want. Why to create the PVC?
2. If you delete the PV with a PVC bound to
   it with `persistentVolumeReclaimPolicy: Retain`, then the PV
   wouldn't get deleted, but would stay in `Terminating` state. Still,
   I am not sure if you can re-use this PV with `Terminating` state.

[Openshift](https://docs.openshift.com/container-platform/3.3/dev_guide/persistent_volumes.html) explains this as **Binding** and **Pre-binding**. Still doesn't give any details of the use cases.

**EDIT**

I know what is a PV and a PVC, and when to use them, so no need to explain the basics. I want to know the use case of creating both at the same time.

Comment: Check this [kubernetes documentation](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/storage/persistent-volumes/#reclaiming) about reclaiming, it should answer question number 2.

Comment: Yes, I think this answers the second question, so you play with the PVCs (by deleting and recreating them) to manage the PV. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

The Persistent Volume is something physical let's say. An entity that exists just like node. On the other hand the PersistentVolumeClaim is just a request from a user.

Making an analogy you must think that the PersistentVolume is a node, and PersistentVolumeClaim is a pod. As pods consume node resources, PVCs consume PV resources.  As it is stated in the [official documentation](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/storage/persistent-volumes/) :

> While PersistentVolumeClaims allow a user to consume abstract storage resources, it is common that users need PersistentVolumes with varying properties, such as performance, for different problems. Cluster administrators need to be able to offer a variety of PersistentVolumes that differ in more ways than just size and access modes, without exposing users to the details of how those volumes are implemented.

In conclusion, I would say that PersistentVolumes and PersistentVolumeClaims are two complementary elements of the PV Subsystem, which work together and this is how the whole system was designed to be used from the beginning. The logical and natural way to go is to create the PV firstly, and then the PVC which needs to work with it. Now that there are different possible ways to achieve some stuff, this does not mean that it is the recommended, or the way it was designed to be.

[image]

Comment: I know what is PV and PVC for. My question is for a specific scenario.

Comment: I understand that. But what I wanted to say regarding your question - "Now, my question is why? Why do we need to create a PVC and then the PV?" - You do not create PV after the PVC and you always need the PVC, because this is how it was meant to function. If you wanna do actions on your PV, you need a PVC. And if you wanted just to store some data and other interactions are not need, you maybe should reconsider using a PV, at all. You would have better options

Answer (score 0):

Pvc enables light coupling between a pod and the persistent volume. The pod is not aware of  what the  underlying storage is and is not necessarily to know that. It just request the storage size it needs to run  the application or service. That pvc claim will identify the persist volume that matches the pod storage requirements and binds the pv to the pod